# Issue deleting Keyword in Tridion

Tags: 2013-sp1, cme, keyword

I'm trying to delete a Keyword in SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 and it doesn´t allow me to do it because "*an element is using this Keyword*", but when I go to see this, elements are all older versions. So actually there are no elements that use my Keyword.

What could be the problem, is there another way to do it?

Comment: You must delete the Older Versions where the Keyword is used. I don't see any other option.

Comment: @SaurabhGangwar please post your solution as an answer so it can be accepted

Comment: @BartKoopman Done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tridion makes sure that the Referential Integrity of the Items remain intact and that is why it's not allowing you to delete the Keyword as it's been used in some old versions of other Items.

To delete the Keyword you need to make sure that the Keyword is not used(referenced) in any other Tridion Item(older versions as well).

In your case, to do so first you need to delete old versions of Components where the Keyword is used and then delete the Keyword.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure to find and delete the older versions of components/component template/schema's where the keyword is used.

To make sure to unlocalized these keyword in case if it's localized in the child publication before deletion.